# Discount Coupons Project-.nextGaussian()

Tags: java, random, statistics

I am working on an assignment for my computer science course and in this assignment we have to generate random coupons with a value of between $1000 and $5000. I have most of it done but our teacher wants us to use .nextGaussian to make it more likely to give out a $1000 coupon than a $5000 coupon. Any suggestion as to how I would go about this? I have looked up .nextGaussian but I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. We are using Bluej(java is the programming language) as the environment if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

99% of the results of nextGaussian will be between -3 and 3.  So you probably want to

1. Take the absolute value.
2. Multiply by a large number, roughly 5000/3.

You will have a lot of results between 0 and 1000, not sure how to handle those.  Probably ignore them and go again?  Hopefully this will get you started.  Note that some results will be >5000, definitely ignore those and go again.

EDIT ADDED

About a minute after I answered last night, realized a slightly better way.

1. Take absolute value.  You now have numbers in the range 0...infinity, but mainly in the range 0...3
2. Multiply by 4000/3.  Numbers are now mainly in the range 0...4000
3. Add 1000.  Numbers are now mainly in the range 1000...5000.
4. In the rare case where the number is >5000, just try again.